# Javascript/populate form fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms, populate

I have a basic HTML form which is a table with four fields on either side. Each field has three values: comment, date, sameas

What I am trying to figure out is getting those "same as" menus to populate data into the corresponding field. ie: A user enters a date and comment at Right3 and chooses "Same as Left2," the date, comment and sameas values are automatically populated at Left2.

I am a novice at javascript, but if someone could push me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

**Edit**: I have figured out how to populate the text areas thanks to your code snippets.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/N63ys/) is the result so far

Can I integrate the other two fields into the same function?

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery to get the value of the `select` when it changes (using [change function](http://api.jquery.com/change/))
 and then set the value of the fields related to the `select` to populate the values of the field selected.

It seems complicated but [a example](http://jsfiddle.net/SPL_Splinter/smrFe/3/) should make it easier. Of course it's a very small example but I guess you will be able to do what you want with this example.

Hope it's a little light you can follow. :-)